# quickblox video call not going

Tags: quickblox

> ```
> package com.esolz.sweet_date.sweetdate.fragments;
>
> import android.app.Fragment;
> import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
> import android.content.Context;
> import android.content.Intent;
> import android.content.IntentFilter;
> import android.media.AudioManager;
> import android.media.MediaPlayer;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.os.Handler;
> import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
> import android.util.Log;
> import android.view.LayoutInflater;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.view.ViewGroup;
> import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
> import android.widget.ImageButton;
> import android.widget.ImageView;
> import android.widget.LinearLayout;
> import android.widget.TextView;
> import android.widget.ToggleButton;
>
> import com.esolz.sweet_date.sweetdate.R;
> import com.esolz.sweet_date.sweetdate.helper.ApplicationSingleton;
> import com.esolz.sweet_date.sweetdate.holder.DataHolder;
> import com.esolz.sweet_date.sweetdate.activity.MainActivity;
> import com.esolz.sweet_date.sweetdate.sweetdate.ListUsersActivity;
> import com.quickblox.core.exception.QBResponseException;
> import com.quickblox.users.QBUsers;
> import com.quickblox.users.model.QBUser;
> import com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBRTCSession;
> import com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBRTCTypes;
>
> import java.io.Serializable;
> import java.util.ArrayList;
> import java.util.List;
> import java.util.Map;
>
>
> /**
>  * Created by tereha on 16.02.15.
>  */
> public class VideoConversationFragment extends Fragment implements Serializable {
>
>     private String TAG = VideoConversationFragment.class.getSimpleName();
>     private ArrayList<Integer> opponents;
>     private int qbConferenceType;
>     private int startReason;
>     private String sessionID;
>
>     private TextView opponentNumber;
>     private TextView connectionStatus;
>     private ImageView opponentAvatar;
>     private ToggleButton cameraToggle;
>     private ToggleButton switchCameraToggle;
>     private ToggleButton dynamicToggleVideoCall;
>     private ToggleButton micToggleVideoCall;
>     private ImageButton handUpVideoCall;
>     private ImageView imgMyCameraOff;
>     private TextView incUserName;
>     private View view;
>     private Map<String, String> userInfo;
>     private View opponentItemView;
>     private HorizontalScrollView camerasOpponentsList;
> //    public static LinearLayout opponentsFromCall;
>     private LayoutInflater inflater;
>     private ViewGroup container;
>     private Bundle savedInstanceState;
>     private boolean isVideoEnabled = true;
>     private boolean isAudioEnabled = true;
>     private List<QBUser> allUsers = new ArrayList<>();
>     private LinearLayout actionVideoButtonsLayout;
>     private View actionBar;
>     private String callerName;
>     private LinearLayout noVideoImageContainer;
>     private boolean isMessageProcessed;
>     private MediaPlayer ringtone;
>     private View localVideoView;
>     private View remoteVideoView;
>     private IntentFilter intentFilter;
>     private AudioStreamReceiver audioStreamReceiver;
>     private CameraState cameraState = CameraState.NONE;
>     LinearLayout actionVideoButtons;
>
>     @Override
>     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_chat_view, container, false);
>         this.inflater = inflater;
>         this.container = container;
>
>         Log.d(TAG, "Fragment. Thread id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
>         final Handler h = new Handler();
>         final int delay = 3000; //milliseconds
>         actionVideoButtons=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.actionVideoButtons);
>         h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
>             public void run() {
>                 //do something
>                 actionVideoButtons.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>             }
>         }, delay);
>         ((MainActivity) getActivity()).initActionBarWithTimer();
>
>         if (getArguments() != null) {
>             opponents = getArguments().getIntegerArrayList(ApplicationSingleton.OPPONENTS);
>             qbConferenceType = getArguments().getInt(ApplicationSingleton.CONFERENCE_TYPE);
>             startReason = getArguments().getInt(MainActivity.START_CONVERSATION_REASON);
>             sessionID = getArguments().getString(MainActivity.SESSION_ID);
>             callerName = getArguments().getString(MainActivity.CALLER_NAME);
>
>             Log.d(TAG, "CALLER_NAME: " + callerName);
>
>         }
>
>         initViews(view);
>         initButtonsListener();
>
> //        createOpponentsList(opponents);
>         setUpUiByCallType(qbConferenceType);
>
>         return view;
>
>     }
>
>     private void setUpUiByCallType(int qbConferenceType) {
>         if (qbConferenceType == QBRTCTypes.QBConferenceType.QB_CONFERENCE_TYPE_AUDIO.getValue()) {
>            // cameraToggle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
>             switchCameraToggle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
>
>             localVideoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
>             remoteVideoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
>
>             imgMyCameraOff.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
>         }
>     }
>
>     public void actionButtonsEnabled(boolean enability) {
>
>
>        // cameraToggle.setEnabled(enability);
>         switchCameraToggle.setEnabled(enability);
> //        imgMyCameraOff.setEnabled(enability);
>       //  micToggleVideoCall.setEnabled(enability);
>       //  dynamicToggleVideoCall.setEnabled(enability);
>
>
>         // inactivate toggle buttons
>         //cameraToggle.setActivated(enability);
>         switchCameraToggle.setActivated(enability);
> //        imgMyCameraOff.setActivated(enability);
>        // micToggleVideoCall.setActivated(enability);
>      //   dynamicToggleVideoCall.setActivated(enability);
>     }
>
>
>     @Override
>     public void onStart() {
>
>         getActivity().registerReceiver(audioStreamReceiver, intentFilter);
>
>         super.onStart();
>         QBRTCSession session = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getCurrentSession();
>         if (!isMessageProcessed) {
>             if (startReason == StartConversetionReason.INCOME_CALL_FOR_ACCEPTION.ordinal()) {
>                 session.acceptCall(session.getUserInfo());
>             } else {
>                 session.startCall(session.getUserInfo());
>                 startOutBeep();
>             }
>             isMessageProcessed = true;
>         }
>     }
>
>     private void startOutBeep() {
>         ringtone = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.beep);
>         ringtone.setLooping(true);
>         ringtone.start();
>
>     }
>
>     public void stopOutBeep() {
>
>         if (ringtone != null) {
>             try {
>                 ringtone.stop();
>             } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             } catch (Exception e) {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             }
>             ringtone.release();
>             ringtone = null;
>         }
>     }
>
>
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() from " + TAG);
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>         intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
>         intentFilter.addAction(AudioManager.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
>         intentFilter.addAction(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED);
>
>         audioStreamReceiver = new AudioStreamReceiver();
>     }
>
>     private void initViews(View view) {
>
>
>         localVideoView = view.findViewById(R.id.localVideoVidew);
>         remoteVideoView = view.findViewById(R.id.remoteVideoView);
>
> //        opponentsFromCall = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.opponentsFromCall);
>
>       //  cameraToggle = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.cameraToggle);
>         switchCameraToggle = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.switchCameraToggle);
>        // dynamicToggleVideoCall = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.dynamicToggleVideoCall);
>        // micToggleVideoCall = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.micToggleVideoCall);
>
> //        actionVideoButtonsLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.element_set_video_buttons);
>
>         handUpVideoCall = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.handUpVideoCall);
>         incUserName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.incUserName);
> //        incUserName.setText(callerName);
> //        incUserName.setBackgroundResource(ListUsersActivity.selectBackgrounForOpponent((
> //                DataHolder.getUserIndexByFullName(callerName)) + 1));
>
>         noVideoImageContainer = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.noVideoImageContainer);
>      //   imgMyCameraOff = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgMyCameraOff);
>
>         actionButtonsEnabled(false);
>     }
>     @Override
>     public void onResume() {
>         super.onResume();
>
>         // If user changed camera state few times and last state was CameraState.ENABLED_FROM_USER // Жень, глянь здесь, смысл в том,
> ```
>
> что мы здесь включаем камеру, если юзер ее не выключал
>               // than we turn on cam, else we nothing change
>               if (cameraState != CameraState.DISABLED_FROM_USER
>                       && qbConferenceType == QBRTCTypes.QBConferenceType.QB_CONFERENCE_TYPE_VIDEO.getValue()) {
>                   toggleCamera(true);
>               }
>           }
>
> ```
>     @Override
>     public void onPause() {
>         // If camera state is CameraState.ENABLED_FROM_USER or CameraState.NONE
>         // than we turn off cam
>         if(cameraState != CameraState.DISABLED_FROM_USER) {
>             toggleCamera(false);
>         }
>
>         super.onPause();
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onStop() {
>         super.onStop();
>         stopOutBeep();
>         getActivity().unregisterReceiver(audioStreamReceiver);
>     }
>
>     private void initButtonsListener() {
>
>         switchCameraToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View v) {
>                 if (((MainActivity) getActivity()).getCurrentSession() != null) {
>                     ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getCurrentSession().switchCapturePosition(new
> ```
>
> Runnable() {
>                               @Override
>                               public void run() {
>       //                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cam was switched", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>                               }
>                           });
>                           Log.d(TAG, "Camera was switched!");
>                       }
>                   }
>               });
>
> ```
> //        cameraToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
> //            @Override
> //            public void onClick(View v) {
> ////                if (((MainActivity) getActivity()).getCurrentSession() != null) {
> //                    if (cameraState != CameraState.DISABLED_FROM_USER) {
> //                        toggleCamera(false);
> //                        cameraState = CameraState.DISABLED_FROM_USER;
> //                    } else {
> //                        toggleCamera(true);
> //                        cameraState = CameraState.ENABLED_FROM_USER;
> //                    }
> ////                }
> //
> //            }
> //        });
>
> //        dynamicToggleVideoCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
> //            @Override
> //            public void onClick(View v) {
> //                if (((MainActivity) getActivity()).getCurrentSession() != null) {
> //                    Log.d(TAG, "Dynamic switched!");
> //                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getCurrentSession().switchAudioOutput();
> //                }
> //            }
> //        });
>
> //        micToggleVideoCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
> //            @Override
> //            public void onClick(View v) {
> //                if (((MainActivity) getActivity()).getCurrentSession() != null) {
> //                    if (isAudioEnabled) {
> //                        Log.d(TAG, "Mic is off!");
> //                        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getCurrentSession().setAudioEnabled(false);
> //                        isAudioEnabled = false;
> //                    } else {
> //                        Log.d(TAG, "Mic is on!");
> //                        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getCurrentSession().setAudioEnabled(true);
> //                        isAudioEnabled = true;
> //                    }
> //                }
> //            }
> //        });
>
>         handUpVideoCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View v) {
>                 stopOutBeep();
>                 actionButtonsEnabled(false);
>                 handUpVideoCall.setEnabled(false);
>                 Log.d(TAG, "Call is stopped");
>
> //                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getCurrentSession().hangUp(userInfo);
>                 ((MainActivity) getActivity()).hangUpCurrentSession();
>                 handUpVideoCall.setEnabled(false);
>                 handUpVideoCall.setActivated(false);
>
>             }
>         });
>     }
>
>     private void toggleCamera(boolean isNeedEnableCam) {
>         // TODO temporary insertion will be removed when GLVideoView will be fixed
>         DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
>         displaymetrics.setToDefaults();
>
>       //  ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = imgMyCameraOff.getLayoutParams();
>
>         //layoutParams.height = localVideoView.getHeight();
>        // layoutParams.width = localVideoView.getWidth();
>
>       //  imgMyCameraOff.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
>
> //        Log.d(TAG, "Width is: " + imgMyCameraOff.getLayoutParams().width + " height is:" +
> ```
>
> imgMyCameraOff.getLayoutParams().height);
>               // TODO end
>
> ```
>         if (((MainActivity) getActivity()).getCurrentSession() != null) {
>             ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getCurrentSession().setVideoEnabled(isNeedEnableCam);
>           //  cameraToggle.setChecked(isNeedEnableCam);
>
>             if (isNeedEnableCam) {
>                 Log.d(TAG, "Camera is on!");
>                 switchCameraToggle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>               //  imgMyCameraOff.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
>             } else {
>                 Log.d(TAG, "Camera is off!");
>                 switchCameraToggle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
>               //  imgMyCameraOff.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>
>     public static enum StartConversetionReason {
>         INCOME_CALL_FOR_ACCEPTION,
>         OUTCOME_CALL_MADE;
>     }
>
>     private List<QBUser> getOpponentsFromCall(ArrayList<Integer> opponents) {
>         ArrayList<QBUser> opponentsList = new ArrayList<>();
>
>         for (Integer opponentId : opponents) {
>             try {
>                 opponentsList.add(QBUsers.getUser(opponentId));
>             } catch (QBResponseException e) {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             }
>         }
>         return opponentsList;
>     }
>
> //    private void createOpponentsList(List<Integer> opponents) {
> //        if (opponents.size() != 0) {
> //            for (Integer i : opponents) {
> //                addOpponentPreviewToList(i, opponentsFromCall);
> //            }
> //        }
> //    }
>
>     private void addOpponentPreviewToList(Integer userID, LinearLayout opponentsFromCall) {
>
>         if (opponentsFromCall.findViewById(userID) == null) {
>
>             View opponentItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_opponent_from_call,
> ```
>
> opponentsFromCall, false);
>                   opponentItemView.setId(userID);
>
> ```
>             opponentItemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onClick(View v) {
>                     Log.d(TAG, "Main opponent Selected");
>                 }
>             });
>
>             TextView opponentNumber = (TextView) opponentItemView.findViewById(R.id.opponentNumber);
>             opponentNumber.setText(String.valueOf(ListUsersActivity.getUserIndex(userID)));
>             opponentNumber.setBackgroundResource(ListUsersActivity.resourceSelector
>                     (ListUsersActivity.getUserIndex(userID)));
>
>             ImageView opponentAvatar = (ImageView) opponentItemView.findViewById(R.id.opponentAvatar);
>             opponentAvatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_noavatar);
>
>             opponentsFromCall.addView(opponentItemView);
>         } else {
>             opponentsFromCall.addView(opponentsFromCall.findViewById(userID));
>         }
>     }
>
>     private String getCallerName(QBRTCSession session) {
>         String s = new String();
>         int i = session.getCallerID();
>
>         allUsers.addAll(DataHolder.usersList);
>
>         for (QBUser usr : allUsers) {
>             if (usr.getId().equals(i)) {
>                 s = usr.getFullName();
>             }
>         }
>         return s;
>     }
>
>     private class AudioStreamReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
>
>         @Override
>         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>
>             if (intent.getAction().equals(AudioManager.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)){
>                 Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG " + intent.getIntExtra("state", -1));
>             } else if (intent.getAction().equals(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED)){
>                 Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED " + intent.getIntExtra("EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE", -2));
>             }
>
>             if (intent.getIntExtra("state", -1) == 0 /*|| intent.getIntExtra("EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE", -1) == 0*/){
>               //  dynamicToggleVideoCall.setChecked(false);
>             } else if (intent.getIntExtra("state", -1) == 1) {
>              //   dynamicToggleVideoCall.setChecked(true);
>             } else {
> //                Toast.makeText(context, "Output audio stream is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>             }
>            // dynamicToggleVideoCall.invalidate();
>         }
>     }
>
>     private enum CameraState {
>         NONE,
>         DISABLED_FROM_USER,
>         ENABLED_FROM_USER
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Comment: What's the issue here? we need more details here!